# How can I use Automator to generate a kerberos ticket using KINIT?

Tags: macos, terminal, automator, script

I need to be able to generate a kerberos ticket for my MacBook Pro each time the machine restarts. I can manually run KINIT with my credentials to generate a ticket. What is the best way to automate that process?

Comment: Does `kinit` require any manual input from your side?

Comment: Actually, yes. It prompts me for a password.

Comment: Would using `--password-file` be an option for you? Otherwise it will be difficult to automate.

Comment: I don't mind entering the password. I just want to execute a script through a shortcut of some kind (icon or keyboard) that opens up the terminal app, runs the KINIT command with my domain parameter and gets me to the point of entering in a password. If the script can enter the password for me, even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily package shell commands inside an Automator application (or service) using the “Run Shell Script” action. However, this will run the commands in a non-interactive shell  (for an explanation of the difference between interactive and non-interactive shells, see the [pertinent section of the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html) – simply put, you will not have access to the terminal for the password prompt, and if `kinit` is not aware of this, your script will hang). There are two ways around that:

1. script *Terminal.app* to execute your command instead of executing it directly. In that case, you will need a “Run AppleScript” action instead, containing the following command:

   ```
   tell application "Terminal" to do script "kinit <options>"
   ```

   which will open a new Terminal tab running the given command.
2. use `kinit`’s `--password-file` option and pass it the password inside your workflow, i.e.

   ```
   echo <password> | kinit --passwordfile=STDIN <options>
   ```

   To avoid storing your password in plain text inside the workflow, you can securely store it in the OS X Keychain and retrieve it from there. Although possible via a shell script (the TextMate blog has [details on how to achieve that](http://blog.macromates.com/2006/keychain-access-from-shell/) – be sure to read the comments), there are so many gotchas to that I’d recommend  using a bit of AppleScript and Daniel Jalkut’s excellent *[Usable Keychain Scripting](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/2035/usable-keychain-scripting-for-lion)* app. Once installed, the following bit of AppleScript will retrieve your password (assuming the account name is “kinit”):

   ```
   tell application "Usable Keychain Scripting" to get password of first generic item of current keychain whose account is "kinit"
   ```

   Either wrap it in an `osascript` shell command, i.e.

   ```
   passphrase=$(osascript -e '<command above>')
   ```

   or, as you are using Automator, add an AppleScript action, retrieve the passphrase inside it and pass it to the shell script.

Comment: Thanks Kopischke! 

It took me a little time to get up to speed on the ins and outs of Automator and the scripting syntax. Thanks to you I was able to build an Automator app that generates a kerberos ticket for me. I added the app to my login items so it will run every time I login. Booyah!

Answer (score 2):

Just wanna chime in; i didn't fancy putting my password into the keychain so i wrote a quick applescript to pick up from a user prompt:

```
on run {input, parameters}
tell application "System Events"
    set the_username to do shell script "whoami"
    set the_password to "password"
    display dialog "Enter password" default answer "password" buttons {"OK", "Cancel"} default button "OK" with icon 2 with title "SLAC Kerberos" with hidden answer
    set the_password to text returned of the result
end tell
return {the_username, the_password}
end run
```

of course, you probably wanna put the domain into your username too. and then, from a shell script you can do something like:

```
echo $2 | kinit --password-file=STDIN $1
```

what would be nice would be to check the output form the shell script to check for incorrect passwords etc.